# python X509 zeep

Tags: python, request, x509, zeep

I have some problems with the auth X509 using Python. I'm using zeep library and I am facing two different errors.

The first one is:

> OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

I receive this error when I used this code:

```
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
signature = Signature(key_file='path/Myprivate.pem', certfile='path/Mycert.pem') 
username_token = UsernameToken(username, pwd)
client = Client(wsdl=WSDL,wsse=[username_token, signature])
```

To fix the first error I added Trasport with `Session.verify = False`

```
from zeep import  Client
from requests import Session
from zeep.transports    import  Transport
from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken
session = Session()
session.verify = False
signature = Signature(key_file='path/Myprivata.pem', certfile='path/Mycert.pem') 
username_token = UsernameToken(username, pwd)
client = Client(wsdl=WSDL,wsse=[username_token, signature], transport=Transport(session=session))
```

Using the second snippet I received an error from the partner server (500 invalid XML).

Do you think this code is right and the problem is on the partner's side?

Comment: What is the wsdl that you are using? May we have a link to it?

Comment: To test, if issue is with the partner's side I would recommend to use soapui once and try out.

Comment: Solved the issue. It was a problem on the server side.